# Get error when trying to write to a Parcel

Tags: java, android, parcelable, parcel

In my Parcelable class, inside the `writeToParcel` method, I get this error:

```
Inferred type 'MyObject' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should 
implement 'android.os.Parcelable
```

when I try to write an ArrayList, by this way:

```
dest.writeTypedList(new ArrayList<MyObject>());
```

In my code I can write strings by `dest.writeString`, but when I try to write this `Array` of `MyObject` I get the above mentioned error.

How can I fix this?

What is the best way to write an ArrayList to a Parcel object?

Thank you!

Comment: Does MyObject implement Parcelable?

Answer (score 0):

As @devconsole pointed out, your class MyObject is required to implement 'android.os.Parcelable', pretty much what the error message says.

You can find an example here:

[How can I make my custom objects Parcelable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181526/example-of-implementing-parcelable)

Comment: hi @bgse the message is that in my question: Inferred type 'MyObject' for type parameter 'T' is not within its bound; should 
implement 'android.os.Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

Go to your "MyObject" class and make sure it implements Parcelable, you shall see the error gone